# Make a PHP file with a function

Tags: functions, templates, get-template-part, breadcrumb

I want to use the breadcrumb function as listed here: https://gist.github.com/melissacabral/4032941

Putting the code in functions.php works for me, but I would rather have it in a separate PHP file. How can I make a separate file with the code and load/call the code in template?

Comment: Did you happen to read the small code comments on the top where it says  `Add this to any template file by calling dimox_breadcrumbs()`? Place `dimox_breadcrumbs()` into that template and see if it does that for you.

Comment: yes I read the description, however because of the length of the code, I do not want the code in my functions.php but a separate file. How can I make a separate file for the code?

Comment: The best choice is to put it in the functions file and call it in the templates. By calling the function repeatedly in files you add few more milliseconds if not seconds to your page load time, plus its a bad practice. Declare `dimox_breadcrumbs()` in the functions file and call it in the template files properly..

Comment: Template files should not be handling any type of logic, it should just know a function name, that's all, periodWhat you want to do is just horrible design which leads to template files which is not maintainable and temlates having to do too much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really shouldn't be doing this. Functions belong in the functions file. Period. (Or perhaps in a separate functions file which you [include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) in the main one)

However, if you insist, you can drop functions in any template file you want, because PHP doesn't care. Actually you will need to include it in every template file where you want to call `dimox_breadcrumbs()`. In which case you would have to be careful not to include it twice in one page. So, only insist if you can handle the hassle.